# linting and intellisense on Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, linter

I installed ms-python.python. Normally I use Atom and I switch to VS Code for trying.

I have 2 questions :

- I set linter to flake8 : Is it possible to verify in real time like Atom the python syntax or only possible when I save the file ?
- Also, Atom show the content of vars : [vars in Atom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbD4i.png). There is a way to do the same thing on Visual Studio Code ? [vars in VSC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BVYZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Linting on change is not implemented, but there is a [feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/408) for it
2. I have no issues seeing attributes, but I'm running on the development build of the extension so whatever issue you're running into may not be publicly released quite yet

[image: intellisense]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. There is not an issue, just an improvement. For exemple var altsep shows just string and in Atom it shows the content of the var => '/'.

Comment: Feel free to file a feature request at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python